# exit status 1 and cannot load main class errors

Tags: java

So I created and submitted a solution to the problem "Your Ride is Here" for USACO, but after reading the first test data, it says "Execution Error: Your program exited with exit status '1'" and also it gives me a "could_not_find_or_load_main_class_ride" error. Could someone please explain and/or help me as to fixing this error? I heard that in order to fix the error about could not find or load main class error, I have to properly be able to run it from a java command line??  Any help is greatly appreciated. Code is below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Ride {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ride.out")));

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        String comet = st.nextToken() + "\n";

        st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        String group = st.nextToken() + "\n";

        int product1 = 1;
        int product2 = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < comet.length(); i++) {
            int number = comet.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;
            product1 = product1 * number;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < group.length(); i++) {
            int number2 = group.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;
            product2 = product2 * number2;
        }
        int mod1 = product1 % 47;
        int mod2 = product2 % 47;
        if(mod1 == mod2) {
            pw.println("GO");
        }else {
            pw.println("STAY");
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: class Ride should be a public class?

Comment: This would be silly if this is the case but is the class Ride maybe supposed to be ride? I can't recall if the main method has to be in a public class either ...

Comment: @user3227275 For the very purpose of my task, the class isn not supposed to be a public class, as that would throw another error on a linux grading machine.

Comment: @JesseNelson I'm not sure if making the class lowercase would help.

Comment: How is the code being ran?

Comment: @JesseNelson So it runs fine on my computer, but the problem is that this code is also being submitted to a grading system that is like linux or something (because it's usaco). The grading system is what throws an error for this program, saying the program could not be found or loaded.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be lowercase? The error message says could_not_find_or_load_main_class_ride not could_not_find_or_load_main_class_Ride

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time for me to use USACO, but I think your class name must be `ride`. Please go through the instruction of how to submit carefully.

Comment: Lowercase?? Really??

Comment: Yes. Look at the error message If it was trying to run a class called Ride it would show that capitalization in the error message.

Comment: Yes, I just checked my previous submission. It must be lower case, weird convention, but we need to follow. I think majority of person using Usaco use another language (not java). I moved to leetcode a few years back. Usaco is good for learning, while leetcode is good for your interview preparation.

Comment: Yeah, most people who do usaco tend to use c++.